# Reading a stored SecretKey from file

Tags: android

with this below code i can store SecretKey into file:

```
public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    // Generate a 256-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 256;
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    // Do *not* seed secureRandom! Automatically seeded from system entropy.
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(outputKeyLength, secureRandom);
    yourKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    return yourKey;
}

yourKey = generateKey();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "encrypt" + File.separator, "config.xml");

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
byte[] filesBytes = yourKey.getEncoded();
bos.write(filesBytes);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

now how can i read this file and pass bytes[] into SecretKey variable? for example:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "convert" + File.separator, "config.xml");

BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(file));


int length = (int) file.length();
byte[] audio_data = new byte[length];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((bytesRead = buf.read(audio_data)) != -1) {
    output.write(audio_data, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] inarry = output.toByteArray();
yourKey=inarry;
```

problem is `yourKey=inarry;` and pass bytes into `yourKey` variable, how can i resolve that?

Comment: I really don't get you want to do.You what to write a `byte[]` to a file and read it later?

Comment: @Afshin storing `SecretKey` to file and read it and then pass that into SecretKey  variable such as `yourKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I never do this myself, if you want to write `SecretKey` into a file and read it later, you can use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

`SecretKey` is `Serializable`, so you can use with those 2 funtions.

write like:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("G:\\address.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(yourKey);
oos.close();
fout.close();
```

read like:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("G:\\address.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
SecretKey yourKey = (SecretKey) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
fin.close();
```

But as I told, you should normally never do it like this. If you want to just store your key, you need to use `KeyStore`. If you need to save it for sending, you need to save it encrypted. Key is the most important part of a cryptography algorithm, so you should never save it like this in a file.

Comment: and how can i read? and how can i pass in to `SecretKey` variable

Comment: @DolDurma As I told,I have never done it like this(and I think it should never be done like this). But this is reading/writing `Serializable` object. updated for reading too.